# How to perform multiple left outer join using neo4j

Tags: neo4j

How can I create multiple relationship in neo4j for performing the left outer join

My query in sql in as given below

```
Select SI.SendId,MC.CampaignName,SI.Name,
SI.SendDate,G.Name As GName,C.Name as FN From SendItem SI 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Campaign MC ON MC.CampaignId=SI.MessageCampaignId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups G ON G.Id=SI.GroupId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact C ON C.ContactId=SI.Contact
order by SI.SendDate desc
```

I am new to neo4j so please anyone help me to create relationship to execute the above query in neo4j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about tables as nodes with a label, and about join as a relationships:

Query to create:

```
// Create campaign
MERGE (MC:Campaign {name: 'CampaignName'})

// Create group
MERGE (G:Groups {name: 'GroupsName'})

// Create contact
MERGE (C:Contact {name: 'ContactName'})

// Create item 
MERGE (SI:SendItem {name: 'SendItemName', sendDate: timestamp()})

// Create relationships
MERGE (SI)-[:hasContact]->(C)
MERGE (SI)-[:inGroup]->(G)
MERGE (SI)-[:inCampaign]->(MC)
```

Query to get:

```
MATCH (SI:SendItem)
WITH SI
     OPTIONAL MATCH (SI)-[:hasContact]->(C:Contact)
     OPTIONAL MATCH (SI)-[:inGroup]->(G:Group)
     OPTIONAL MATCH (SI)-[: inCampaign]->(MC:Campaign)
RETURN ID(SI) as id,
       SI.name as sendItemName,
       SI.sendDate as date,
       C.name as contactName,
       G.name as groupName,
       MC.name as campaignName
ORDER BY SI.sendDate desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..But i am facing difficulty in creating relationship for executing the above given cypher...So please help me on how to create relationship